# using an if statement over two columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

I am currently trying to calculate the distance between shotpoints in a seismic navigation file with multiple lines. My current code is as follows:

```
def Delimiter(Filename, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    data = pd.read_fwf(Filename, names=[a, b ,c ,d ,e ,f ], header=None)
    data['lineshift'] = data['line'].shift(-1)
    data['bool'] = data['lineshift'] == data['line']
    for _, row in data.iterrows():
        data['SPDIF'] = np.abs(data['sp'].astype(float) - data['sp'].astype(float).shift(-1))
        data['XDIFF'] = data['X'] - data['X'].shift(-1)
        data['YDIFF'] = data['Y'] - data['Y'].shift(-1)
        data['XYDIFF'] = np.sqrt(data['XDIFF']**2 + data['YDIFF']**2)
        data['SPDIST'] = data['XYDIFF']/data['SPDIF']
        if row['line'] != row['lineshift']:

            data['SPDIF'] = data['SPDIF'].replace({0: np.nan})
            data['XDIFF'] = data['XDIFF'].replace({0: np.nan})
            data['YDIFF'] = data['YDIFF'].replace({0: np.nan})
            data['XYDIFF'] = data['XYDIFF'].replace({0: np.nan})
            data['SPDIST'] = data['SPDIST'].replace({0: np.nan})
    data.info()
    print data

Delimiter(os.path.splitext(x)[0] + ".csv", "line", "sp", "Xcoord", "Ycoord", "X", "Y")
```

This code loads a CSV with shotpoint data into a pandas dataframe. However, I want to check if the code is not calculating the distance between 2 shotpoints of different line. If the 'line' column is different than the 'lineshift' column of the same row, I want it to display N/A. If it's the same then it should calculate 5 new columns for that specific row.

However when I run this code, it gives the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

If possible, what would I need to add to make this code run and check every row?

An example of the data in the CSV file:

```
      line    sp    ycoord     xcoord    x       y          lineshift
8     761298  1080  521754.1N  65132.6E  255355  479838     761298   True
9     761298  1090  5218 2.5N  65154.3E  255760  480107     761298   True
10    761298  1100  521812.1N  65216.0E  256165  480410     761298   True
11    761298  1110  521820.7N  65236.8E  256554  480685     771022  False
12    771022  1020  521835.8N  65238.3E  256573  481153     771022   True
13    771022  1030  521841.0N  65245.2E  256700  481315     771022   True
14    771022  1040  521845.8N  65252.2E  256830  481466     771022   True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: `data['lineshift'] == data['line']` is a series, not a boolean, so `if data['lineshift'] == data['line']` is ambiguous.

I think you meant to test the current row in the loop, something like:

```
    for _, row in data.iterrows():
        if row['lineshift'] == row['line']:
            # ...
```

---

**Edit**: this fixes the error you reported, but you should not use a loop here.

```
def Delimiter(Filename, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    data = pd.read_fwf(Filename, names=[a, b ,c ,d ,e ,f ], header=None)
    data['lineshift'] = data['line'].shift(-1)
    data['bool'] = data['lineshift'] == data['line']
    # calculate this only once
    data['SPDIF'] = np.abs(data['sp'].astype(float) - data['sp'].astype(float).shift(-1))
    data['XDIFF'] = data['X'] - data['X'].shift(-1)
    data['YDIFF'] = data['Y'] - data['Y'].shift(-1)
    data['XYDIFF'] = np.sqrt(data['XDIFF']**2 + data['YDIFF']**2)
    data['SPDIST'] = data['XYDIFF'] / data['SPDIF']

    data.loc[~data['bool'], ['SPDIF', 'XDIFF', 'YDIFF', 'XYDIFF', 'SPDIST']] = np.nan

    data.info()
    print data
```

Comment: using if row['lineshift'] == row['line']: gives me the following error: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Note that this will fix the error you reported. The code inside the if/else statement still needs some work.

Comment: yeah, it seems to run now, however none of the values where the line doesnt match get replaced. do you know how to set row values of multiple columns to 0 or n/a? ive edited my current code in the post

Comment: strange, it still shows values for the line that are supposed to be replace with n/a.

Comment: I suspect that you don't have any values that are `0` to begin with, so they are not replaced with `NaN`. Could that be the case?

Comment: yes i think so. what i basically want is those rows where 'bool' is false to not calculate any of the extra columns like SPDIF, XDIFF. would like to replace those cells with N/A so they wont be taken along if i were to calculate average SP distances per line. thanks for the major help, as you can see im not that experienced with python, let alone Pandas.